# How to run rollback custom action in Wise Installer Editor?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, wise, ca

I'm making an installer that uses certain custom actions. I want to create a rollback action that undoes this changes when the installation is cancelled or unsuccessful.

What I've tried so far is what the documentation tells you to do, which is call the CA in deferred-mode and set "rollback only" in the In-Script Options. if you cancel the installation,  the moment the installer tries to call the CA, the installation fails, it doesn't matter what the content of the CA is, it always fails the moment the installer tries to call it.
It says the installer couldn't execute a find a program necessary for the installation (the CA), even though the CA is called with "Run WiseScript From Installation", so the CA SHOULD be there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the setup is hitting an error inside your rollback custom action. The first thing I would do to prevent the setup from bombing out would be to mark the rollback custom action with "don't check exit code".

I haven't used Wise in a while and don't know exactly where you find this in the GUI, but it shouldn't be that difficult. It is probably a flag you can set when you insert the custom action into the InstallExecuteSequence.

Secondly you would need to start debugging the actual content inside the custom action to determine where it crashes and obviously resolve the root of the problem before the rollback action will work properly. Sometimes it is sufficient to just use numbered message boxes to track the progress of the code in the custom action at runtime, but at other times you need to use the debugger feature to step through each line in the custom action code.